# How do I prove this derivation?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, logarithms

I hope you can help me with this one because I seem to not quiet get a start here :/

Lets say we got a  $b\in\mathbb{R}_{\gt 0}$ and a $y\in\mathbb{R}$
and we define $b^y:=\exp\left(\ln b \cdot y\right)$.

How do I prove that the derivation of a function $$f:\mathbb{R}_{\gt 0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x^a$$ with a well defined $a\in\mathbb{R}$
is $f'(x) = ax^{a-1}$?

Comment: Our function is by definition $\exp(a\ln x)$. Differentiate, using the Chain Rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, we have $x^a=\exp(a\ln x)$. Differentiate, using the Chain Rule. We get 
$$\frac{a}{x}\exp(a\ln x).\tag{1}$$
Using $\frac{1}{x}=\exp(-\ln x)$, we can rewrite (1) as $a\exp((a-1)\ln x)$, that is, as $ax^{a-1}$.

Comment: I got most of it but i dont seem to get how u rewrote (1). Would you mind to explain that to me? i´m confused as to where the -1 comes from

Comment: We have $a\exp(-\ln x)\exp(a\ln x)$. Using $\exp(s)\exp(t)=\exp(s+t)$ we get $a\exp(-\ln x+ a\ln x)=a\exp((a-1)\ln x)$. By definition $\exp((a-1)\ln x)=x^{a-1}$.

Comment: thank you I understood it now :)

Comment: You are welcome. Early on in calculus, we find the derivative of $x^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer. We are now dealing with $x^a$, where $a$ need not be an integer. We f\just found that the familiar formula still holds, but the proof has to be different.

Comment: Was just thinking about why it is still correct when i choose e.g a= 1,21 and f´(x) = 1,21 * x^0,21 .  Actually its pretty cool that it still works :D